# How to force Google Earth to open pictures with Firefox or default browser?

Tags: firefox, google-earth

Is there a way to force Google Earth latest version (7.1.1) to open pictures and Wikipedia articles on directly Firefox or a default browser, instead of using its own GUI?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

After you open the photo in the Google Earth browser, look in upper right for a (very small ) button that lets you open the photo in your default browser.

See screenshot for example.

[Source](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/earth/SjMQlPkypSU)

[image]

Comment: Yeah, no, what i meant was if i could open the photos directly on a browser with out having to go through Google Earth's embedded browser, but thanks anyway.

Comment: @Oily I still maintain what I have described answers the question asked.